# CSS doesn't recognize min-width media query

Tags: css, media-queries

I don't know why my CSS `media` query is not working properly:

```
/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {
.bottom-right{margin-top:20%;}
.bottom-right h2{font-size: 0.9em;}
.buttons{font-size: 1.0em;}
} 

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (min-width : 993px) {
.solodesktop{display:block;}
.solomobile{display:none;}
.bottom-right{margin-top:10%;}
.bottom-right h2{font-size: 7em;}
.buttons{font-size: 0.8em;}
}
```

In the page, the `margin-top` property of `.bottom-right` class does not a apply a top margin of 20%.

[image: css margin top rule not working]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of your current media queries is causing the problem.

When forking around the `min-width` values, you should always put them in to ascending order when it comes to the pixel values. Swap places with `min-width: 993px` and `min-width: 1200px` and it should run smooth.

Other option is to also set the `max-width` value to the media query (see Roman's answer), so it knows not to interfere with the next query. CSS is always being read from the **top to bottom**, so the last rule overrides the previous if you're not specific enough.

Answer (score 0):

Your media queries are not precise enough, the second query starts at 993px and has no max. limit, which means it overrides the first media query. That happens because due to the fact that css rules are applyed top-down it overrides your first media query.

To fix this you could say:

```
/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (min-width: 993px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
.solodesktop{display:block;}
.solomobile{display:none;}
.bottom-right{margin-top:10%;}
.bottom-right h2{font-size: 7em;}
.buttons{font-size: 0.8em;}
}
```

Here is the css desk, it works now [CSS Desk Code](http://www.cssdesk.com/uh63y)

Under 993px it has default html styles, between 993px and 1199px it does margin 10% etc. and at 1200px (min-width: 1200px) it changes margin etc.

Comment: seems legit but doesen't worjk :-(

Comment: I made a typo, its 1199px ofc. try it now